# Is this, 'just any', a mate?

Tags: vocabulary, negation

> The recipe uses a large amount of pepper, and **not just any** pepper, but a special blend imported from India. ([Merriam-Webster’s](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/any))
>
> You have to be a member to go there. They won't let **just any** person in. (Merriam-Webster’s)
>
> We don’t publish just any letters: we reject more than half of those submitted. (CGEL,p.383)

When we use free choice *any* in negative contexts, do we have to add an intensifier, *just*? From my mother tongue’s aspect, logically, it seems to be added to the free choice *any*. But the grammar book doesn’t say about that. Whereas the dictionary’s both online and its Learner’s paper book has bold characters for these two words - *just any*’s, seemingly saying they are a mate. Without *any*, don’t we use the expression, or does the word, *just*, only clarify the speaker’s intention of negating the free choice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, you need to include *just* in this construction. For instance, in two of your examples, removing *just* changes the meaning:

> They won't let any person in
>   We don’t publish any letters

Without *just*, these statements indicate that nothing whatsoever is permitted; *no people are let in* and *no letters are published*. If you put the surrounding context back in, the meaning becomes evident, but then there's a semantic mismatch and confusing language.

Ellipting *just* works better in the pepper example, because the construction is *[X], and not any [X] but [specific X]*. The context before and after (mostly after; *but* does the heavy lifting here) *not any* makes it obvious there's an exception to the rule of *not any pepper*, so it's not nonsensical like the other two. However, it still reads better with the intensifier, because *just* helps emphasize how special and important the Indian pepper is, which is the purpose of this phrasing.

An equivalent phrase for *just any* is [*any old*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/any+old). This is idiomatic, with *old* meaning, roughly, *generic*, and not *aged*. This is informal, and as with *just any*, removing *old* changes it into a blanket statement.

Comment: I'll say that in spoken English, you can probably elide the _just_ - I'd expect a medium-falling intonation on the _any_ would connote the same meaning.